# retrieve the remaining credits of their accounts using SMPP (CloudHopper)

Tags: java, sms-gateway, smpp

i am trying to retrieve my remain credit on viva network which use SMPP protocol 
i have used a cloud hopper implementation to send SMS but i can't retrieve my remain balance details : please need your help

Answer (score 2):

The SMPP protocol has nothing to do with the balance. Its sole purpose is to send and receive short messages and no more. You need to contact your service provider and ask how to retrieve such information.

Comment: Normally such providers have a separate HTTP API or Webservice for getting current balances.